# Python - Accessing a Dropdown Menu with Selenium that Only Populates when clicked with a mouse

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am using Selenium with Python to scrape elements of a website and interact/fill them out. I am able to select aspects up until reaching a final Drop Down menu that does not seem populated with values unless clicked upon by a user. My script currently is able to select the drop-down menu and click on it, but the entries I want to select do not appear and cause my script to timeout while waiting for the drop-down entry I want to choose.

Drop down menu when selected by selenium:
[image]

While this timed-out browser is open I am able to click on the drop-down menu and the options fill in.

Drop-down menu after being timed out and clicked by me manually:
[image]

I have tried using Selenium to double-click on this drop-down menu however this does not succeed in populating the drop-down menu. I am using the WebDriverWait() method to allow all elements to load before scraping the CSS on the webpage, and this has allowed me to select and interact with elements before this one, including another drop-down menu. No matter how long I wait the validation entry will not show up until I click on it manually with a mouse.

The section of my code that deals with this drop down menu is as follows

```py
    # Wait and then click on the "Validation" dropdown using the <tb-drop-down> element
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(lambda success: success.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tb-drop-down[data-qa='select-validation-types']"))
    search_site = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tb-drop-down[data-qa='select-validation-types']")
    search_site.click()

    # Wait until "Full Validation" option appears and then click on it using the <mat-tree-node>
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=15).until(lambda success: success.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "mat-list-option[class='mat-list-item mat-list-option mat-focus-indicator list-option-item tb-h-30 mat-accent']"))
    validation = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "mat-list-option[class='mat-list-item mat-list-option mat-focus-indicator list-option-item tb-h-30 mat-accent']")
    validation.click()
```

The HTML for the drop-down menu when I select it is also below

```
<tb-tree _ngcontent-fvx-c114="" _nghost-fvx-c108="" class="ng-star-inserted">
<div _ngcontent-fvx-c108="" class="tb-multi-select">
<!---->
<mat-selection-list _ngcontent-fvx-c108="" role="listbox" disableripple="" class="mat-selection-list mat-list-base tb-top-padding-0" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
<!---->
<mat-list-option _ngcontent-fvx-c108="" role="option" class="mat-list-item mat-list-option mat-focus-indicator list-option-item list-option-item-none tb-h-30 mat-accent ng-star-inserted" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">
<div class="mat-list-item-content mat-list-item-content-reverse">
<div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-list-item-ripple">
</div>
<!---->
<div class="mat-list-text">
<span _ngcontent-fvx-c108="">-- None --</span>
</div>
</div>
</mat-list-option>
<!---->
<!---->
<mat-tree _ngcontent-fvx-c108="" role="tree" class="mat-tree cdk-tree">
<mat-tree-node _ngcontent-fvx-c108="" mattreenodetoggle="" mattreenodepadding="" class="cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node expendable-disabled ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="1" aria-expanded="false" style="padding-left: 0px;">
<mat-list-option _ngcontent-fvx-c108="" role="option" class="mat-list-item mat-list-option mat-focus-indicator list-option-item tb-h-30 mat-accent" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">
<div class="mat-list-item-content mat-list-item-content-reverse">
<div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-list-item-ripple">
</div>
<!---->
<div class="mat-list-text">
<template _ngcontent-fvx-c108="">
</template>
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-fvx-c108="" class="tb-center-items ng-star-inserted">
<!---->
<span _ngcontent-fvx-c108="" queryselector="" class="mat-tooltip-trigger ellipsis tb-display-block ng-star-inserted" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-13" cdk-describedby-host="">1 - Full Validation</span>
<!---->
<!---->
</div>
<!---->
<!---->
</div>
</div>
</mat-list-option>
<!---->
</mat-tree-node>
<!---->
</mat-tree>
</mat-selection-list>
</div>
<!---->
</tb-tree>
```

I am not sure if there is a difference between the way selenium clicks vs. how a click is registered via a mouse button that could be causing this behavior. I have tried searching for how to access CSS elements that are hidden away/waiting for events like a click. However, the CSS element that I am looking for is not present when I inspect the webpage once it times out and fails to populate the list.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the _Drop-down menu_ and your code trials.